# Eclipse Galileo supports javascript cross-file code completion, but Eclipse Helios does not?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-completion, helios, galileo

When editing multiple javascript files, each of which are supposed to be available in the global scope because - for example - they will each be loaded in the same html document, Galileo supported this little trick to put comment tags for other files that are required to be available in the same scope:

myfile.js:

```
// @include "somefile.js"
// @include "otherfile.js"
```

And you have cross-file code completion in myfile.js.

But now that I moved to Eclipse Helios, this doesn't work anymore. Did they move similar functionality to some other method?

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe your Helios installation somehow has an older version of the JS tools? Try going to Help > Check for Updates...

Comment: Nice guess, indeed I had a nice flock of updates. But no Javascript ones. (Probably unrelated, but I also run Helios on Windows 7 and used Gelileo on Ubuntu 10.4. You never know.)

Comment: Are you sure it's the same JavaScript tools in both?

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked that for you: I am using the Spket JS Editor. (The default one is useless for JSON-style coding.)

Comment: Since Spket doesn't come as part of Galileo or Helios, you might want to update the question to accurately reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

My Eclipse Helios installation with Spket works just fine.

Just FYI:

**Eclipse**:

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

**Spket:**

Version: 1.6.18

In file One.js:

```
var varOne = 
{
    test: function(){}
}
```

In file Two.js on Ctrl-Space (or .):

[image]

As you can see - `test` function is visible.

**EDIT**:

also, what's the policy on resurrection of 2 months old questions?

Comment: The policy is: Thank you. I've never gotten this to work. But it doesn't work for me anyhow. I just don't get any of the js objects in there. It's just that basic list:

`break
case
cache
const
...`

I just reinstalled both Helios on Windows 7 and Galileo on Ubuntu 11.04, both with SPKET js editor, and Galileo just does this out of the box and Helios doesn't mention anything js-ish. Is there an extra step in the Windows way of getting this to work?

Comment: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/dM2ub) (screenshot goes with previous comment.)

The outliner seems to work fine though. Also local file only, not the @included one.

Comment: I am not sure I've done anything extraordinary. I don't have Helios at work, but I have Indigo, without Spket. I will install Spket (need to anyway :)) and see what gives.

EDIT: actually Spket won't install on Indigo at all. We'll see...

Comment: For some reason I can't install Spket at all (not on Helios and not on Indigo)...

I will have to try it later.