# Node.JS debugging with Eclipse and Chromium Dev Tools V8

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, v8, google-chrome-devtools

Eclipse is a you-love-it or you-hate-it tool for editing Javascript files. For me, it's both.

Anyway, I often prefer the [SPKET JS editor plugin](http://www.spket.com/download.html) for Eclipse over the default one because of small details like [object knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006421/eclipse-javascript-code-highlighting-json-style-js-does-half-a-job) and [included file code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256636/eclipse-galileo-supports-javascript-cross-file-code-completion-but-eclipse-heli).

However, when using the V8 debugger from [Chrome Dev Tools](http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn/update/dev/) for server-side JavaScript like Node.JS, it opens a third editor Chromium (from the browser) for code stepping.

I would like everything in one tab, so I tried opening my files with the JS editor from the V8 tools, but the name in the tab is now hidden (try editing multiple files this way) and a new one opens up on debugging anyway*.

(* Note that PHP debugging has a similar problem, but it opens a new instance from the same PHP editor)

*Chromium JS editor | SPKET JS Editor | Eclipse JS Editor*
[image]

Also, I don't know if this is node-specific or Eclipse-specific, but `node --debug` doesn't seam to do anything, no variable outlining, no breakpoints. Whereas `node --debug-brk` does as expected. So either Node.js is weird, Eclipse is, I've missed the point or I've set up debugging wrong.

Could anyone elaborate on debugging server-side JS in Eclipse and using the most complete JS editor, so that:

- JS editor is aware of functions inside objects and separate files like SPKET (Often the case in modern implementations like Node.js) but preferably free for any use (like Chromium Dev Tools)
- Eclipse keeps code and debugging in the same tab (if at all possible)
- Tabs keep the name of the files (bug or wrong setting?)

I am running Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 with Google Chrome Developer Tools SDK WIP + remote debugging + JSDT bridge and - if relevant - optionally SPKET 1.6.20 IDE, on Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

--edit--

At least I figured out where to put the breakpoints. Not in the editor, but in the debugger. Open the `Project Explorer`:

Window -> Show View -> Other... -> General -> Project Explorer

In Project Explorer -> Select your debug item -> Open proper JS file -> 
[image]
THIS is where you want to add breakpoints.

Comment: just a remark regarding `node --debug`. That will start the script with remote debugging enabled but actually run the script. So you should be able to open one of the scripts that gets executed set there a breakpoint and when it is reached nodejs should stop on the set breakpoint and you should be able to step through the code. `node --debug-brk` starts nodejs already suspended.

Comment: Yes, I've recently noticed that `--debug-brk` automatically connects to the proper 'editor' so the breakpoints actually work. Setting breakpoints in your default editor using `--debug` aren't attached to the proper debugger or something, and I haven't yet figured out how to connect the two (your default editor and the debugger I mean).

Comment: The answer by beefeather explains how to get the non-breaked debug to use your preferred editor for setting breakpoints without needing a separate window for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChromeDevTools by default has its own separate .js files for debugging. If you want to have debugger stepping in your files, you would need to set this up:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/FeatureDebugOnRealFiles